# Is there a way to further simplify this vector algebra term?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

I am currently deriving the kinematics of a complex robotic system, and after a lot of calculations arrived at this final vector equation that fully describes the system$^1$
\begin{align*}\omega &= -2\arctan\left(\frac{k_1\mp \sqrt{k_1^2-\left(k_3-k_2\right)\left(k_2+k_3\right)}}{k_3-k_2}\right) \text{ where}\\
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
 k_1^j &= \hphantom{-} \mathbf{z}_{\hat{3}} \cdot \left(\mathbf{z}_1\times \mathbf{z}_2\right)\\
 k_2^j &=  -\mathbf{z}_{\hat{3}}\cdot \left(\mathbf{z}_1 \times \left(\mathbf{z}_1\times \mathbf{z}_2\right)\right)\\
 k_3^j &= \hphantom{-} \mathbf{z}_{\hat{3}} \cdot \left(\mathbf{z}_1\times \left(\mathbf{z}_1 \times \mathbf{z}_2\right)\right) + \mathbf{z}_2\cdot\left(\mathbf{z}_{\hat{3}}-\mathbf{z}_3\right).
\end{align*}
$\mathbf{z}_1,\mathbf{z}_2,\mathbf{z}_3,\mathbf{z}_{\hat{3}}$ are four distinct $3\times 1$ vectors of the form 
$$\mathbf{z}_i = \begin{pmatrix}\cos(\varphi_i)\sin(\Theta_i)\\\sin(\varphi_i)\sin(\Theta_i)\\\cos(\Theta_i)\end{pmatrix}.$$ 
$\cdot$ is the dot product and $\times$ is the cross product.

If substitued into the equation, the argument of the $\arctan$ becomes

$$\frac{\mathbf{z}_{\hat{3}}\cdot \left(\mathbf{z}_1\times\mathbf{z}_2\right)\mp\sqrt{\left[\mathbf{z}_{\hat{3}}\cdot\left(\mathbf{z}_1\times\mathbf{z}_2\right)\right]^2-\left[2\mathbf{z}_{\hat{3}}\cdot\left(\mathbf{z}_1\times\left(\mathbf{z}_1\times\mathbf{z}_2\right)\right)+\mathbf{z}_2\cdot\left(\mathbf{z}_{\hat{3}}-\mathbf{z}_3\right)\right]\left[\mathbf{z}_2\cdot\left(\mathbf{z}_{\hat{3}}-\mathbf{z}_3\right)\right]}}{2\mathbf{z}_{\hat{3}}\cdot \left(\mathbf{z}_1\times\left(\mathbf{z}_1\times\mathbf{z}_2\right)\right)+\mathbf{z}_2\cdot\left(\mathbf{z}_{\hat{3}}-\mathbf{z}_3\right)}.$$

As this term will be utilized for all further calculations, including symbolic ones, it would be very useful to simplify it as far as possible. Are there any vector algebra tricks that I could apply to this expression?

Thank you in advance, and Merry Christmas!

$^1$ For the curious, $\omega$ is the joint angle of an actuator and $\mathbf{z}_i$ are joint axes of a leg connecting the actuator with the effector.

Comment: With the triple [product formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_product#Vector_triple_product), we have
$$
z_1 \times (z_1 \times z_2)  = (z_1 \cdot z_2) z_1 - (z_1 \cdot z_1) z_2,
$$
which eliminates most of the cross-products. The remaining cross-products are part of a [scalar triple-product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_product#Scalar_triple_product). Note that $z_1 \cdot z_1 = \|z_1\|^2$.

Comment: Do we know in advance that any pair of vectors will be parallel/perpendicular?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I've already played around a bit with the vector and scalar triple product formula. However, I can't find any straight forward way to simplify the term more than that, if it is possible at all. And unfortunately, it is known that none of the vectors are colinear or perpendicular to each other, so only strictly algebraic manipulations are possible.

Comment: I'd start by precomputing $z_1\times z_2$ and calling it (say) $z_{12}$

Comment: @user721481 I'm not really sure if this will simplify the equation in any way, as all components of a vector are independent of another. I'm looking for algebraic manipulations that would simplify the term, otherwise I could simply let the computer calculate the expanded symbolic form and call it done. I've added the components of $\mathbf{z}_i$ for further clarification.